# Zend\Mvc\Controller\PluginManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for init

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm maintaining a PHP Zend application.  I'm attempting to add functionality to it.

I'm trying to call a Controller through a phtml file.  I'm thinking I'm approaching this the wrong way, but I'm not sure what the correct way is.

I've modified three files and added another.  I've added code to FileController.php.

```
public function getModifiedBy($filename) {
    $groupFiles =$this->getServiceLocator()->get('qatools\Model       \GroupFilesTable');
    $modified = $groupFiles->fetch($filename);
    return $modified;
}
```

I've also added code to job-wizard.phtml.

```
<?php
use qatools\Controller\FileController;

$fileControl = new FileController;
$fileControl->init();
$modified =$fileControl->getModifiedBy("addresscleaningservice.xlsx");
?>
```

The new file is 'GroupFileTable.php' which extend AbstractModelTable and queries a MySQL database.  I added the following lines to module.config.php.

```
'qatools\Model\GroupFilesTable' => function($sm) {
    return defModelTable($sm, 'GroupFilesTable');
    },
'GroupFilesTableGateway' => function($sm) {
        return defModelTableGateway($sm, 'group_files', 'GroupFiles');
            },
```

The code is failing on $fileControl->init() in job-wizard.phtml.  I tried taking out that line, but then the code failing on the getServiceLocator call.

```
#0 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library     /Zend/ServiceManager/AbstractPluginManager.php(103): Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->get('init', true)
#1 /mnt/c/git-repos/qatools/vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Mvc/Controller/PluginManager.php(82): Zend\ServiceManager\AbstractPluginManager->get('init', NULL, true)
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what version of Zend Framework are you using, anyway whatever version is, you should not create an istance of a controller within a view script.

In ZF, if you need to call a view functionality, a better approach is to create a view helper, the logic between ZF1 and ZF2/3 is the same, only the implementation changes, I'll leave to you google searches to see examples, your final view script code should be something like the follow

```
<?php echo $this->getModifiedBy("addresscleaningservice.xlsx"); ?>
```

The viewHelper will contain the logic. If at some point you'll need to reuse this logic within a controller or in whatever other place, my advice is to create a component with the logic, then create a service that returns the instance of this component and eventually create an action helper ( $this->myComponent in any controller ) and a view helper ( $this->myComponent in any view ) and inject the same component instance.

Comment: I am using Zend 2.3.  I'm creating a view helper to see if that will work.  Thanks for the advice.